# sql automatic changing column names

Tags: oracle

i am trying to change the column name of my query
it will be a lot more helpful if i show you

here is what i am trying to do
at the moment i have a query

```
select count (driverid) as "scheduled deliveries"
from
lbs_drivers
join lbs_people using (personid)
join lbs_schedule using (driverid)
where driverid = 1
```

this is what i get

scheduled delivries = 2 (which is correct)

however the driverid's name is qasim 
what i am trying to do is when i run the query i want the drivers name to be the columns name

so the query result should be

```
qasim = 2
```

another example would be

```
joe bloggs = 4
amy = 1
```

any please help
many thanks

Comment: add name column from lbs_people to the select column list

Comment: well select (and group by) the name (We don't know which table / column is containing this name, so hard to be more precise)

Comment: i think you are looking for dynamic pivot, but in oracle, until i know it's not possible, at least in sql

Comment: I guess you are looking for column values to be displayed as column name. This cant be done. refer - https://community.oracle.com/message/12417185